# Unicode string literals in C# vs C++/CLI

Tags: c#, unicode, c++-cli, unicode-literals

```
C#:
char z = '\u201D';
int i = (int)z;

C++/CLI:
wchar_t z = '\u201D';
int i = (int)z;
```

In C# "`i`" becomes, just as I expect, 8221 ($201D). In C++/CLI on the other hand, it becomes 65428 ($FF94). Can some kind soul explain this to me?

**EDIT**: Size of `wchar_t` can not be of issue here, because:

```
C++/CLI:
wchar_t z = (wchar_t)8221;
int i = (int)z;
```

Here too, `i` becomes 8221, so `wchar_t` is indeed up to the game of holding a 16-bit integer on my system. [Ekeforshus](http://www.vdsoft.se)

Comment: Your second example doesn't prove size is not an issue -> does z in the second example == z in the first example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
wchar_t z = L'\x201D';
```

from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx).  \u is undefined.

Comment: ... and should have given you a /W1 warning "unrecognized character escape sequence".

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character):

> "The width of `wchar_t` is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8 bits. Consequently, programs that need to be portable across any C or C++ compiler should not use wchar_t for storing Unicode text. The wchar_t type is intended for storing compiler-defined wide characters, which may be Unicode characters in some compilers."

You shouldn't make any assumptions about how it's implemented.